# Pull specific field from nth index of Knockout observableArray of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a page that displays a list of file templates built using the following method.

```
var loadCustomTemplate = function () {
    loadBaseTemplate();
    var res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < self.GetSeam().length; i++) {
        var a = self.count() + 1;
        self.count(a);
        res = self.GetSeam()[i].FileFormat.split("_");
        if (res.length == 4) {
            var ap = res[3].split('.');
            self.append(ap[0]);
        } else {
            self.append("");
        }
        var obj = {
            Code: ko.observable(self.code()),
            Number: ko.observable(self.number()),
            SeamReportPath: ko.observable(self.reportPath()),
            FileFormat: ko.observable(self.append()),
            SequenceNumber: ko.observable(a)
        }
        self.CustomTemplate.push(obj);            
    }
    self.count(0);
};
```

The user is then allowed to edit the fields as needed.  They can also add records or remove them as needed. The method to add a record is as follows.

```
self.addTemplate = function () {      
    var count = self.CustomTemplate().length + 1;  
    var obj = {
        Code: ko.observable(self.code()),
        Number: ko.observable(self.number()),
        SeamReportPath: ko.observable(self.reportPath()),
        FileFormat: ko.observable(""),
        SequenceNumber: ko.observable(count)
    }
    self.CustomTemplate.push(obj)
};
```

Once those updates are made they can save the updated CustomTemplate. This uses ajax that is not important to this question. The save method calls a validation method that is supposed to check to make sure there are no duplicate FileFormat fields in the object array.  This is what I have, but it is failing.

```
var validateTemplates = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < self.CustomTemplate().length; i++) {
        var checkVal = self.CustomTemplate()[i].FileFormat;
        var checkSeq = self.CustomTemplate()[i].SequenceNumber;
        for (j = 0; j < self.CustomTemplate().length; j++) {
          if (checkSeq !== self.CustomTemplate()[j].SequenceNumber ){  
            if (checkVal+"" === self.CustomTemplate()[j].FileFormat) {
                if (checkSeq == self.CustomTemplate()[j].SequenceNumber ){
                    return false;
                }
            }                   
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

The problem is that when checking self.CustomTemplate()[i].FileFormat and  self.CustomTemplate()[i].SequenceNumber it isn't reflecting the data displaying on the page or the data being sent to the controller (MVC 4). If I put either of those in an alert it is showing a function. How do I access the data in those specific fields for comparison?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Knockout observables are functions. To `set` their value, you call them with a parameter. To `get` their value, you call them without a parameter. I.e.: `var a = ko.observable(1); a(2); console.log(a());` prints `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put either of those in an alert it is showing a function.

That's because you're doing this kind of thing:

```
var checkVal = self.CustomTemplate()[i].FileFormat;
```

`FileFormat` is the result of `ko.observable(...)`, which returns a *function*, so `checkVal` in fact does contain a function.

The solution is for all those cases to do this:

```
var checkVal = self.CustomTemplate()[i].FileFormat(); // Parentheses at the end!
```

The parentheses *execute* the observable function, and if you do so without parameters you "get" the value of that observable. (If you would pass in a value, it would "set" the observable to that value.)

Comment: Thanks! Still getting used to the ins and outs of Knockout.